# Use iPhone to recognize sound frequency in range 20-24 Hz

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, signal-processing, frequency

My boss wants me to develop an app, using iPhone to recognize sound frequencies from 20-24 Hz that humans cannot hear. (iPhone frequency response: 20 Hz to 20 kHz)

Is this possible?  If yes, can anyone give me some advice? Where to start?

Comment: check out this blog post: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html maybe you can edit the code to find a 20-24 hz pattern in a sound sample file.

Comment: If you have it as a recording it may be possible, the mic can't detect such low frequencies.

Comment: Needs `elephant` tag ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant#Communication ?

Comment: Just wants to send some special message that user won't notice.

Comment: Wow. Actually an interesting idea but the mic won't pick it up I'm afraid.

Comment: The messages will need to be *very* short - at such a low frequency you would only practically be able to communicate at around 5 bps (yes, 5 *bits* per second).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you start working on this you need to make sure that the iPhone hardware is physically capable of detecting such low frequencies. Most microphones have very poor sensitivity at low frequencies, and consumer analogue input stages typically have a high pass filter which attenuates frequencies below ~ 30 Hz. You need to try capturing some test sounds containing the signals of interest with an existing audio capture app on an iPhone and see whether the low frequency components get recorded. If not then your app is a non-starter.

Comment: A little dated but [this](http://blog.faberacoustical.com/2009/ios/iphone/iphone-microphone-frequency-response-comparison/) and [this](http://blog.faberacoustical.com/2010/ios/iphone/iphone-4-audio-and-frequency-response-limitations/) might be interesting. More than 50Hz seems to be the lowest possible frequency I would bet money on. From my own experience less than 100Hz was very difficult to track musical notes (ie: I gave up).

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a fast fourier transform.  This is the main algorithm used for converting a time based signal to a frequency based one.

It seems the Accelerate framework has some FFT support, so I'd start looking at that, there are several posts about that already.

Apple has some sample openCL code for doing this on a mac, but AFAIK openCL isn't on iOS yet.

You'd also want to check the frequency response of the microphone ( I think there are some apps out doing oscilloscope displays from the mic that would help here).

You basic method would be to take a chunk of sound from the mic.  Filter it and then maybe shift it down in frequency, depending on what you need to do with it.

Comment: Maybe. The FFT is commonly used for this sort of thing, but it's not a cure-all. There's not much room for data between 20-24 Hz, and if the response of the phone is low, there will have to be lots of redundancy, too. This blog post might help you get started, though: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html